# Disabling specific cell edit in Slick grid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Is there a way to disable a cell for editing? We can define editor at column level but can we disable that editor for specific rows?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
grid.onBeforeEditCell.subscribe(function(e,args) {
  if (!isCellEditable(args.row, args.cell, args.item)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 - A much better solution! I've never used this grid before so I immediately resorted to 'hacking' away at it. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9fMD/4/) to compliment your answer. It simply disables editing in the 4th row.

Comment: Fantastic solution!! I should've thought of it :P

Answer (score 1):

You can disable or even change editor/formatter/validator... or other cell properties using `getItemMetadata` method. There is very nice documentation for this [here](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Providing-data-to-the-grid).
**Example:**

```
$scope.data.data.getItemMetadata = function (row) {
  var item = $scope.data.data.getItem(row);
  if (item.some_condition) {
    return {
      columns : {
        yourColumnId : {
          editor : null,
          formatter : function () { return 'custom formater if some_condition'; }
        }
      }
    };
  }
};
```